# LocationClient not working with Google Play services imported properly

Tags: java, android, gps

I need some help with a little error I'm getting when using Google Play Services.
I have to make an update to an existing application; the application is fully functional and it uses some of the features GPS has to offer.
Today I downloaded the app's code from BitBucket and when I import it, there's an error with LocationClient.
I followed the Google instructions again to make sure everything was alright but I'm still getting the following error:

```
LocationClient cannot be resolved to a type
```

In this class:

```
package com.racsa.oncecincocinco;

import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.*;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

public class ActivityRacsaLocalizador extends FragmentActivity implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener{

    private static final String TAG = "ActivityRacsaLocalizador";

    // These settings are the same as the settings for the map. They will in fact give you updates
    // at the maximal rates currently possible.
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    private LocationClient clienteLocalizacion;


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inicializarClienteLocalizacionSiEsNecesario();
        clienteLocalizacion.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        if (clienteLocalizacion != null) {

            if (clienteLocalizacion.isConnected()){
                clienteLocalizacion.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            }

            clienteLocalizacion.disconnect();
        }

        super.onStop();
    }

    private void inicializarClienteLocalizacionSiEsNecesario() {
        if (clienteLocalizacion == null) {
            clienteLocalizacion = new LocationClient(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    this,  // ConnectionCallbacks
                    this); // OnConnectionFailedListener
        }
    }


    public Location getLocalizacionActual() {
        Location miLocalizacion = null;

        if (clienteLocalizacion != null && clienteLocalizacion.isConnected()) {
            miLocalizacion = clienteLocalizacion.getLastLocation();
        }

        return miLocalizacion;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        clienteLocalizacion.requestLocationUpdates(
                REQUEST,
                this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // Do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do nothing
    }


    /**
     * Implementation of {@link LocationListener}.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

I dunno what's happening, please help me!

Edit:
Here's the Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.racsa.oncecincocinco"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="20"
    android:versionName="3.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="false"
        android:smallScreens="false" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icono_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAYGybtYRnkT5x5BvPjx7r0nBHVBwRXI90" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.Splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.Principal"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.Preferencias"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarAnunciante"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.SimpleOptionMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ActivityMenuHolder"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MenuLista"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.RegistroUsuario"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarAnuncianteInfo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.CrearComentario"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ListaComentario"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarInfoComentario"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.CrearLista"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MisListas"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MisListasTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.BuscarListas"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarListasBuscar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MisListasAgregarAnunciante"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarListasInfo"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MostrarListasInfoBuscar"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.MapaGuia"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.Promocion"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.VerInfoPromocion"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ListaPromocion"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ActivityEscogerPlan" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity><activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ActivityMostrarMapa"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ActivityFiltrarRealidadAumentada"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/StyledIndicators" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.racsa.oncecincocinco.ActivityLanzarRealidadAumentada"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:launchMode="singleInstance">
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService"
            android:exported="false" />

        </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: show your gradle file...Most probably you are compiling the latest play services

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with ADT.. Let me show you the manifest file

Comment: Just added the manifest file, thank you

Comment: no need you must be importing the latest play services...if in your sdk manager you have updated Google play services!If that is the case then look at this link how to setup LocationClient http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html.The method you are using now was used for Google Play services 6.1

Comment: Thank you so much! I downgraded the GPS and worked! Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!
I did a downgrade for GPS and it worked for now.
Next time I do an update, imma change the version to its newest.